# What is the probability of an event happening after n series of times

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I am learning to code in python and so for academic reasons i have decided to code this project. What tests should i do which will answer this question? In monsoon season, what is the probability that we will have a sunny day after a series of rainy days, or the opposite what is the probability of rain in summer after a series of sunny days? I have the data to work with so is there a nice and tidy formula for computing such probabilities?

Comment: You need a model to relate the events in your data. What kind of model are you looking for?

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica I dont have a strong math background, so I am willing to work with multiple models so it will give me an opportunity to evaluate them. I guess with models you mean like regression, linear ... Why dont you recommend me where i should get started with your pick of top 3 models. I also want to visualize this data such as a with a bell curve. Thanks! :)

Comment: Well for a student I'd suggest considering a simple Markov chain model. These have been used in practice for problems like this, and at the same time learning about them will be useful in other ways. Its also a good starting point for modelling dependence

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to estimate a Negative Binomial Distribution.

> In probability theory and statistics, the negative binomial
>   distribution is a discrete probability distribution of the number of
>   successes in a sequence of independent and identically distributed
>   Bernoulli trials before a specified (non-random) number of failures
>   (denoted r) occurs. For example, if we define a 1 as failure, all
>   non-1s as successes, and we throw a dice repeatedly until 1 appears
>   the third time (r = three failures), then the probability distribution
>   of the number of non-1s that appeared will be a negative binomial
>   distribution.

That's from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution

The Negative Binomial Distribution (NBD) is also called the gamma-poisson distribution.

This is a common distribution, so there's likely a Python function for it, but I'm not literate in Python.

Comment: Thanks, I think i was looking for this !

Comment: I think this suggestion is unrealistic, because daily weather is noticeably correlated, whereas the motivation for the NB distribution explicitly requires *independent* variables.

Comment: @whuber What would you suggest? I am willing to work with multiple ideas. Thanks!

Comment: @whuber Quick question, if it rains for 3 days the probability of not raining the 4th day in monsoon, would that not be considered a independent event since the season is monsoon?

Comment: @whuber's concern is worth addressing. You may find that there's too much correlation to get a sufficient fit.  The NBD does decently well though in a lot of contexts that aren't independent -- product purchase being an example.

Comment: Quick response: as the length of the rainy spell increases, what do you suppose happens to the probability that the next day will be sunny?  If there's any evidence that this probability depends on the length, then the observations are not independent.

Comment: @whuber forgive me as i am new to this. My question is, why is it different from say coin flip where suppose you flip a coin a few times to tail, the probability that the next flip will be head increases too, but this is considered an independent event?

Comment: That is a mistake: no matter how many times the coin has come up tails, its chance of coming up heads is always the same.  Weather does not work like coins.